# Updating application to heroku

Tags: python, ruby-on-rails, git, heroku

I have running app on heroku server. I cloned it make some changes and I want push it back. I added remote heroku repo to my local repository but when i want to push it:

```
Fetching repository, done.
Counting objects: 5, done.
Delta compression using up to 2 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (3/3), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes | 0 bytes/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 2), reused 0 (delta 0)

Connection to 10.185.171.142 closed by remote host.
, done.
error: did not receive remote status
```

**Update**
when I run git remote -v:

```
heroku git@heroku.com:wierszyki.git (fetch)
heroku git@heroku.com:wierszyki.git (push)
origin git@heroku.com:wierszyki.git (fetch)
origin git@heroku.com:wierszyki.git (push)
```

Comment: What do you see if you run `git remote -v`?

Comment: And are you still getting errors when pushing? That 'connection closed by remote host' can be due to flaky internet,  and might have gone away on its own.

Answer (score 0):

I would probably say it's either a `heroku authentication` or `git remote` problem

--

**1. Heroku authentication**

When you push to any remote `git` repo, you will have to authenticate with the service.

Most services use an [RSA-key](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/RSA_(cryptosystem)) for encrypted SSH transfer, meaning if you want `heroku` to accept your incoming push, you'll have to make sure you're authenticated correctly.

As you've cloned the `repo` from a `remote` repo already, you may have to re-authenticate with `Heroku` -- a process which can be achieved primarily by downloading or re-installing the [`heroku toolbelt`](https://toolbelt.heroku.com/)

If you download this & reauthenticate your system, it may clear up your issues

--

**2. Remote Git**

You may also have an issue with the `remote` `git`

If you've just cloned the repo, I would surmise you may have an issue with the way the `remote` repo is being connected. The surest way to fix this is to just get rid of the `remote` `heroku` repo & add a new one:

```
$ git remote rm heroku
$ git remote add heroku git@heroku.com[your repo]
```

Answer (score 0):

Note that the error message "did not receive remote status" is about to change with Git 2.13 (Q2 2017)

See [commit d1a13d3](https://github.com/git/git/commit/d1a13d3fcb252631361a961cb5e2bf10ed467cba), [commit ba69f92](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ba69f92db6033d6187414c57547e8f79d6aa7f1b), [commit 40d05d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40d05d04dd338f80b5392e8dea3a5c854798351e), [commit f7cd74d](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f7cd74d19d3e2a194760024046534adf20f9efde), [commit 7c39df2](https://github.com/git/git/commit/7c39df2979733e0041db7aff09c3f3a53b980ef2), [commit 6cdad1f](https://github.com/git/git/commit/6cdad1f133475f2bff0dfe2fbe90c351df3ea61d) (07 Mar 2017) by [Jeff King (`peff`)](https://github.com/peff).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit f4d3af1](https://github.com/git/git/commit/f4d3af185988ad45ebc0a6dead32222cad2c03a6), 24 Mar 2017)</sup>

In particular, [commit 40d05d0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/40d05d04dd338f80b5392e8dea3a5c854798351e) includes:

> ### `send-pack`: improve `unpack-status` error messages
>
> When the remote tells us that the "unpack" step failed, we show an error message. **However, unless you are familiar with the internals of send-pack and receive-pack, it was not clear that this represented an error on the remote side.**
>   **Let's re-word to make that more obvious**.
>
> Likewise, when we got an unexpected packet from the other end, we complained with a vague message but did not actually show the packet.
>   Let's fix that.

The error message becomes:

```
unable to parse remote unpack status
```